# Error in building Apache Giraph Core

Tags: maven-3, hadoop2, giraph

I'm trying to install Giraph  in single node following this link:
http://lab.hypotheses.org/1207
 by using Java JDK 1.8 and hadoop 2.4.0.
When I run: mvn -Phadoop_yarn -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests package , I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core
[INFO] Apache Giraph Blocks Framework
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples
[INFO] Apache Giraph Distribution
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Giraph Parent 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mavanagaiata:0.5.0:branch (git-commit) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mavanagaiata:0.5.0:commit (git-commit) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.2:enforce (default) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] Skipping Rule Enforcement.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-versions-check-plugin:2.0.2:check (default) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.4:process (default) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-only (default) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] Skipping plugin execution
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-duplicate (default) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] Skipping plugin execution
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-dep-mgt (default) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] Skipping plugin execution
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-duplicate-finder-plugin:1.0.4:check (default) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.3:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ giraph-parent ---
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Giraph Core 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mavanagaiata:0.5.0:branch (git-commit) @ giraph-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mavanagaiata:0.5.0:commit (git-commit) @ giraph-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.2:enforce (default) @ giraph-core ---
[INFO] Skipping Rule Enforcement.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-versions-check-plugin:2.0.2:check (default) @ giraph-core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- munge-maven-plugin:1.0:munge (munge) @ giraph-core ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent ............................... SUCCESS [  5.569 s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core ................................. FAILURE [  0.459 s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Blocks Framework ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.320 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-22T09:53:47+03:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/450M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.plugins:munge-maven-plugin:1.0:munge (munge) on project giraph-core: The parameters 'symbols' for goal org.sonatype.plugins:munge-maven-plugin:1.0:munge are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :giraph-core
```

there are some topics like this but i didn't get the answer, Could any one help me?